# Do the fiber bundles over an Abelian category form an Abelian category?

Tags: category-theory, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, abelian-categories

Assume I have an Abelian category $C$. Is the category of fiber bundles, where the fibers are objects of $C$ Abelian?

Comment: Can you say exactly what you mean by "the category of fiber bundles where the fibers are objects of $C$"?

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all clear what this should mean in general. To define fiber bundles with fiber $F$ requires that you specify a *topological* group $G$ acting on $F$, and if we're just given that $F$ is an object in some abelian category then it just has some automorphism group with no obvious topology in play other than the discrete topology. Picking the discrete topology does not, for example, reproduce real vector bundles if we pick the abelian category to be $\text{Vect}(\mathbb{R})$; the construction of vector bundles is sensitive to the topology of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ but the bare abelian category structure of $\text{Vect}(\mathbb{R})$ is not.

In any case, the category of vector bundles already fails to be an abelian category, e.g. it does not have kernels; see, for example, [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107101/is-the-category-of-vector-bundles-over-a-topological-space-abelian).

In a positive direction, for a topological space $X$ and an abelian category $C$ we can define the category $\text{Sh}(X, C)$ of sheaves of objects of $C$ on $X$, and this is an abelian category; see, for example, [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935308/is-the-category-of-sheaves-of-objects-from-an-abelian-category-abelian) (**Edit:** or maybe not, the linked answer only cites a claim in Weibel without a proof so who knows).

Comment: It feels like some condition on $\mathcal{C}$ or $X$ will be needed to guarantee that sheafified cokernels exist.

Comment: @Zhen: hmm, you might be right, the linked answer only cites Weibel without a proof and Weibel has lots of mistakes... the nLab says for $\text{Sh}(X, C)$ to be nice $C$ should be Grothendieck but doesn't elaborate: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sheaf+of+abelian+groups

Comment: A Grothendieck abelian category is certainly nice enough. You can directly implement sheafification and AB5 guarantees that it will be exact. For general abelian $\mathcal{C}$ I'm not even sure what the correct definition of a sheaf of $\mathcal{C}$-objects should be. Here's a construction: embed $\mathcal{C}$ as an exact full subcategory of a Grothendieck abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, construct the category of $\mathcal{A}$-sheaves, then define $\mathcal{C}$-sheaves to be those $\mathcal{A}$-sheaves whose stalks are in $\mathcal{C}$. This category is abelian, but it's not the obvious one!