# Epimorphism between sheaves in arbitrary category

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$,$\mathcal{G}$ are 2 sheaves valued in an arbitrary category(such that all limits and colimits(hence the stalks of sheaves) exist) on a topological space $ X$, and $f\colon \mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G} $ a morphism between sheaves, what is the condition that $f $ is an epimorphism.

It is clear when $\mathcal{F} $ and $\mathcal{G} $ are sheaves of sets, which is, for every open subset $U$, there exists an open cover $\{U_i,i\in I \} $, such that the restriction of $s\in \mathcal{g}\left(U\right)$ on each $U_i$ comes from the image of $f_{U_i}\colon \mathcal{F}\left(U_i\right)\rightarrow\mathcal{G}\left(U_i\right) $. For sheaves in arbitrary category, what I had guessed is that$f $ is epimorphic if the restriction morphism $\mathcal{G}\left(U\right)\rightarrow\mathcal{G}\left(U_i\right) $ can be factored through $f_{U_i} $, but I failed to prove that this gives an epimorphism of sheaves, so does the construction given above gives an epimorphism, and does every epimorphism satisfies the condition shown above? If not, what is the condition for a sheaf morphism being epimorphic?

Comment: It is not good to define "sheaves valued in an arbitrary category" in that way. As you have discovered yourself, it is difficult to prove the properties we want to be true at that level of generality. See my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3958950/5191).

Comment: @ZhenLin Your objection seems good to me if one wants to define, say what a "sheaf of fields" is. But if $\mathcal C$ is complete and cocomplete, then isn't it quite standard to define a $\mathcal C$-valued sheaf on $X$ to simply be a functor $F: Open(X)^{op} \to \mathcal C$ satisfying the sheaf condition? Anyway, a characterization of epimorphisms which works in some but not all cases is to check that the map is an epimorphism on stalks.

Comment: @tcamps I explained my objections to the "standard" definition [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389377/).